# Moving a root directory to a separate partition

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, security, partition, webserver

I'd like to create a new partition and move the contents of the `/var` directory to it for the security reason of having `/var/www` and other subdirectories "mounted" with `nosuid`, `noexec`, and `nodev` permissions. How do I do it for `/var` or any other root directory?

Comment: So you want a single `nosuid` etc. partition for `/var`, or a separate partition per subdirectory?

Comment: @Useless Just one partition and just for `/var` alone.

Comment: / itselv is more difficult. But you did not ask about that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, a slight modification to warl0ck's plan (because I'm paranoid)

1. create the new partition
2. boot to single-user mode
3. mount the new partition as `/new_var` or something, and rsync as described

   - you might as well run `aptitude autoclean` before running rsync, to reduce the amount getting copied over (or even `... clean` if you don't mind re-downloading your apt cache)
4. move `/var` to `/old_var` so you don't lose it right away, and then mount the new partition as `/var`

   - there may be live logs or pid files in `old_var` - if you don't mind losing whatever changed since re-starting, you can ignore those
5. edit fstab so the new partition will mount as `/var` on future boots, and  reboot to normal multi-user mode
6. *if* all that went well, you can `sudo rm -fr /old_var` when you're sure it's working. If anything breaks, you still have `old_var` around

Comment: The copy/rsync/whatever should be done in single-user mode too.

Comment: Good point, I've edited that in.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is mount the new partition on some temporarily location, then do a `rsync` to synchronize `/var/` and the new location,

Afterwards, boot to root maintain mode, erase `/var`, and change fstab that mount the new partition onto /var